# Has anyone administered a CASB? Looking for opinions, tips, advice, etc

Tags: casb

My company is investigating the CASB (Cloud Access Security Broker) space.  We're evaluating a few vendors, specifically:
- Skyhigh
- Netskope
- Bitglass
- CipherCloud

Has anyone administered a CASB as part of their duties?  I'd love some feedback about the vendor(s) that you use, general tips and advice, or any other relevant comments.

Thanks in advance.